# How can I change the name of the query result tabs in Navicat?

Tags: navicat

I'm running multiple queries at once and was wondering if I can assign different names to each of the tabs, so that the names are more useful than "Result 1", "Result 2", etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can name the results tab by adding a special comment just before each query. The comment should be in the following format:

```
-- NAME: your-tab-name
```

Where `your-tab-name` can be anything you want. Here's an example:

```
-- NAME: premium users
select * from users where premium = 1;

-- NAME: others
select * from users where premium = 0;
```

Now instead of the tabs being named "Result 1" and "Result 2", they will be named "premium users" and "others".

You can also use the block comment syntax instead:

```
/* NAME: premium users */
select * from users where premium = 1;

/* NAME: others */
select * from users where premium = 0;
```

Here's an example of what named tabs would look like:

[image: Navicat named tabs example]

Comment: Thanks. This deserves best answer!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It this feature just for premium/full versions? i use navicat lite.

Comment: it works thank you mate

`-- NAME: payment`;
`SELECT * FROM invoice_payments;`